# Separar por párrafos un array

Tags: linux, bash

Intento realizar un script en bash y tengo un array que se divide en 3 párrafos separados por un salto de línea:

`echo "${myarray[@]"`

> Este es el ...
> ... primer párrafo.

> Este es el ...
> ... segundo párrafo.

> Este es el ...
> ... ultimo párrafo.

---

¿Cómo haría el bucle (o lo que sea) para que se muestre párrafo por párrafo?

Ej:

Párrafo 1: $i

Comment: Qué tal compañero, te invito a relizar el [tour] para ganar tu primera medalla. Adicionalmente puedes leer la sección de [ask], en la que encontraras entre otros consejos, el de incluir un [mcve] e incluir dudas respecto al código o lo que haz intentado. Recuerda que puedes editar la pregunta en cualquier momento para agregar más información.

Comment: por favor provee de código completo para poder reproducir el problema. ¿Cómo defines el array? Dale a [edit] para completar los datos

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar a usar el salto de linea \n. Mira este ejemplo a ver si te funciona en lo que necesitas.
El parámetro -e te permitirá usar estos saltos.

```
echo -e "${myarray[@]}\n"
```

Aunque te recomiendo que uses printf.

```
printf "%s\n" ${parrafos[@]}
```

Comment: Te doy un voto positivo y te complemento con una variante a tu respuesta: `$ printf "%s\n" ${parrafos[@]}`

Comment: Olvídalo. Lo acabo de revisar bien y tu respuesta no cumple con párrafos que contengan espacios. Pero mi propuesta si funciona. Te convendría añadir mi propuesta a tu publicación para tomar en consideración cuando el párrafo contenga espacios.

Comment: Se me paso por completo %s en el formato de printf, Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con el viejo truco de cambiar el IFS:

```
$ (IFS=$'\n'; echo "${myarray[*]}")
```

Y utilizar el token "*" que indica que lo "desempaquetado" se separe por lo que tenga la variable IFS en lugar de por espacios.